# A catch with Dirac Delta Function

Tags: distribution-theory

We know that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} f(t)\delta(t) \mathrm{d}t = f(0)
$$
if $f$ is continuous. What will it be if $f$ is not continuous?
For instance, what is the value of
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}} e^t\mathrm{u}(t)\delta(t) \mathrm{d}t
$$

Comment: Typical strategy:  Apply Laplace transform.

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Dirac delta is linear operator acting on the space of continuous functions, not the integral against something. You might try to approach $\delta$ by a sequence of $C^\infty_c$ functions in the sense of distributions and then try look what it gives when applied to your test function.

Comment: That doesn't help as the answer depends on the particular function I choose to approach the $\delta$ function.

Answer (score 1):

The smoothness of $f$ doesn't play a role, it just makes a non-distribution proof available; see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/73013/52893). If you want to make things rigorous, the best viewpoint is as $\delta_a(x):=\delta(x-a)$ as the distribution which maps $\int_\mathbb{R}f(x)\delta_a(x)\,dx$ to $f(a)$.

Thus, $$\int_\mathbb{R} e^t u(t)\delta(t)\,dt=e^t u(t)\Big|_{t=0}=e^{0}\cdot 1=1$$ by the sifting property of the Dirac delta. The last step depends on [how you define $u(t)$ at $t=0$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heaviside_step_function#Zero_argument).