# What is exactly the test function in real analysis?

Tags: real-analysis

I try to understand test functions to compare two functions $f_1$ and $f_2$ through integration. can someone explain test function to me simply? in other words, i want to understand the answer to my other question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2407347/take-limit-of-maxwell-boltzmann-distribution/2407382#2407382).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A test function is (or can be) literally any function that is non-negative, smooth and with compact support. *edit: non-negativity is optional, and there can be additional requirements as well but this is the spirit*.

The name comes (as far as I know) from distribution theory: a distribution is a linear form on the space of test functions, and therefore you can tell two distributions apart by *testing* them (evaluating them) against test functions.

The first example of distribution that you ever meet is the integration over the real line of your test function times a fixed measurable function: $$\varphi \mapsto \int_\mathbb {R}f(t)\varphi(t) dt $$
This is pretty obviously a linear form, sort of dual to $ f $. You can use it to test $ f $, collect information about it.

How to think about this product $f\varphi$: since $\varphi$ has compact support, so does the product - everything outside the support is killed, and the value of the above integral gives you information about what $f$ does on the support of $\varphi$. You can be quite extreme in the way you localise, by having the support of $\varphi$ shrink to a single point. There is a quite instructive result as follows:

> **Theorem.** If $f$ is a continuous map, and if $\varphi_k$ is a sequence
>   of test functions whose support $[a_k, b_k]$ is such that $\lim a_k = \lim b_k = x$, and if
>   $\int_\mathbb{R} \varphi_k =1$ for all $k$, then $$\lim \int_\mathbb{R} f\varphi_k=f(x)$$

All limits are for $k\to \infty$.

This tells you that you can recover completely the values of $f$ by testing it extremely locally. You can clearly see why the continuity of $f$ is necessary: otherwise the integral of $f$ would have nothing to do with the value it takes at a particular point.

The $\phi_k$ in the above theorem can easily be achieved using Gaussians:

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot, but can you explain it with some example in more details.

Comment: I added a result which is quite enlightening imho.